# конвертация ipv6 из uint64 в строку

Tags: golang, ipv6

подскажите пожалуйста, стоит цель конвертации IPv6 адреса поступающие на вход функции в виде uint64 конвертировать в строку.

пример входящих адресов:

```
281470698815488
281470719218688
281472894533631
42540619364094646098263619931788541952
47852694705315621578891566497667219455
50521211371231186380467345572837195775
58569107375850417935858934690443427839
...
```

на выходе надо получать удобочитаемые адреса в виде (2001:0db8:11a3:09d7:1f34:8a2e:07a0:765d)

в случае с IP адресами v4 все просто обошлось:

```
func inet4_ntoa(ip uint64) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", byte(ip>>24), byte(ip>>16), byte(ip>>8),
        byte(ip))
}
```

c 6-й версией адресов не могу сообразить в какую сторону рыть и

Comment: `ipv6` поступать как `uint64` не может, т.к. `ipv6` хранится как 128-битное число, которое состоит из 8 групп (разделенных `:`) по два байта, а в строку они преобразуются в шестнадцатеричная формате.

Answer (score 0):

Для конвертации IPv6-адреса, представленного в виде uint64, в удобочитаемую строку можно использовать следующую функцию:

```
func inet6_ntoa(ip uint64) string {
    // Разбиваем uint64 на два uint32
    var high uint32 = uint32(ip >> 32)
    var low uint32 = uint32(ip & 0xffffffff)

    // Конвертируем каждый uint32 в 16-ричное число
    // и добавляем в строку с разделителями
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x:%x", high, low)
}
```

Эта функция разбивает uint64 на два uint32, а затем конвертирует каждый uint32 в 16-ричное число с помощью функции fmt.Sprintf. После этого она объединяет эти два числа с разделителем ":".

Пример использования функции:

```
fmt.Println(inet6_ntoa(281470698815488))  // выведет "0:1a3"
fmt.Println(inet6_ntoa(281470719218688))  // выведет
```